# Angular 4 + D3v4 : dragging circle not working correctly in conjunction with zooming

Tags: angular, d3.js

I am trying to create a D3 force-directed graph (https://github.com/d3/d3/blob/master/API.md#forces-d3-force) in an Angular 4 application.

It renders correctly dragging by it's self works, zooming and panning works by it's self, but when you use both of them together (dragging and zooming), it stops to work incorrectly.

I drag a circle, and when I stop dragging, it appears like the circle is still selected and continues to drag.

I have created a sample project and the code can be found here: https://github.com/danielamigos/angular-graphs

To see it in action, here: https://danielamigos.github.io/angular-graphs/dist/index.html

Comment: The problem is not the dragging of nodes but the translation part of the zoom. On mouseup of the drag the zoom-transform is translated as if the mouse movement was also a pan/translate operation. The zoom still assumes we are panning, the translate part of the `g` changes, until we have a mousedown-mouseup outside one of the nodes. If I write the same code in a standalone html using d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js the effect is not there. I think npm/Angular d3v4 has a problem with the event handling.

Comment: i think that may be the case. I tried one of the samples like given [here](https://bl.ocks.org/puzzler10/4438752bb93f45dc5ad5214efaa12e4a) which is working fine with d3.v4.min.js.

Comment: @radbrawler: in the package.json d3.v4.11 is requested. In the example d3.v4.13 is used.

Answer (score 0):

As rioV8 mentioned, this issue is that the node translate and the panning of the canvas are working at the same time. So the solution is, when dragging a node, to stop panning the canvas. This can be done by stopping the propagation of the event when we are dragging the node. So in the **dragstarted(d)** event handler, add this line of code at the beginning:

```
d3.event.sourceEvent.stopPropagation();
```